# Frankly, so far, so dull?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I dont understand this expression 'Frankly, so far, so dull' in this paragraph:

*'When his father died, he slaughtered his brothers to capture the throne. He then invaded the neighbouring state of Kalinga, killing 100,000 men,
women and children. **Frankly , so far, so dull**. History is littered  with corpses on battlefields'* (it is about the man named Ashoka)

(from 'History of the world Episode 3 - The word and the sword' by Andrew Marrs)

Comment: It's elliptical. When you fill in the implied syntax you get something like: "Frankly, so far this story is so dull it is boring me to tears." The important thing to remember is that "the story" is the implied subject.

Answer (score 3):

It's a play on the phrase:

> *So far, so good*

This simply means that everything's been good up to this point. The writer has used the word *dull* where we might expect the word *good*. He hopes that this is going to make the writing dry and witty.

The word *frankly* is used to introduce something that people might find a little rude or critical. It makes it blunter than it otherwise would be.

Here is the page for *so far so good* at [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/so-far-so-good).

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Thanks for the suggestion. Duly added :)

Comment: The inadequacy of using only commas in different roles in close proximity is brought out here. I'd use an ellipsis after 'frankly' here to avoid possible confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The comment reflects a rather overused device in literary and film criticism. The critic, recounting the work's plot, interjects "so far, so ghastly", "so far, so predictable", or whatever adjective seems apposite at the time. It of course mirrors the more familiar cliché, "So far, so good", aiming to tickle the reader with an unexpected allusion. Usually, the hoped-for witty effect falls pretty flat for me, but *de gustibus* and so on...